# 550-Verification failed with few email domains

Tags: php, email, dns, sendmail

I've been working in this for some hours but I cannot find the solution. For some reason I cannot deliver emails to certain domains, I'm using default phpmail function with sendmail. I guess that it's because then they are forwarded to gmail accounts. I just have the smtp configured but I don't receive emails on the webpage server, I just send them from the webpage server.

My sendmail path in php.ini is:
sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i -f'support@email.myweb.com'

support@email.myweb.com is a working email, in another server machine.

This is the Data log error:

```
--t7J8AAkG002350.1439971810/myweb.com--

From MAILER-DAEMON  Wed Aug 19 08:10:44 2015
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
    by myweb.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4) id t7J8AiZE002360;
    Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:44 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:44 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201508190810.t7J8AiZE002360@myweb.com>
To: <www-data@myweb.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="t7J8AiZE002360.1439971844/myweb.com"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--t7J8AiZE002360.1439971844/myweb.com

The original message was received at Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:42 GMT
from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<emailwitherrors@forwardeddomain.com>
    (reason: 550-Verification failed for <www-data@myweb.com>)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to forwardeddomain.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-Verification failed for <www-data@myweb.com>
<<< 550-No Such User Here"
<<< 550 Sender verify failed
550 5.1.1 <emailwitherrors@forwardeddomain.com>... User unknown
<<< 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
<<< 503-Sender verify failed
<<< 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA

--t7J8AiZE002360.1439971844/myweb.com
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; myweb.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:42 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; emailwitherrors@forwardeddomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; forwardeddomain.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-Verification failed for <www-data@myweb.com>
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:44 GMT

--t7J8AiZE002360.1439971844/myweb.com
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Return-Path: <www-data@myweb.com>
Received: from myweb.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by myweb.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4) with ESMTP id t7J8AgZE002358
    for <emailwitherrors@forwardeddomain.com>; Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:42 GMT
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by myweb.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id t7J8AgsO002357;
    Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:42 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 08:10:42 GMT
Message-Id: <201508190810.t7J8AgsO002357@myweb.com>
To: emailwitherrors@forwardeddomain.com
Subject: ¡Welcome to my webpage!
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:whatever.php
From: myweb no-reply <no-reply@myweb.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

--t7J8AiZE002360.1439971844/myweb.com--
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issues due to sender verification. You are sending mails through php mail and due to that server is sending that mail from www-data@myweb.com account and this mail account is not created on your server and due to that recipient mail server is rejecting that mail.

Comment: And how to change that? My sender email in phpmail is no-reply@myweb.com